# CTCI 4.3: Given a binary tree, design an algorithm which creates a linked list of all the nodes at each depth

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, graph-algorithm

I'm solving this problem with Ruby, and I used a modified DFS algorithm to do it. The idea is that, every time DFS has to look at adjacent nodes, then it's looking at the children and therefore that's a new level, recorded as such in the hash below.

Is this implementation/thought process correct? And on that note, what's an efficient way for me to check my own implementation without creating different binary trees for input?

```
#Given a binary tree, design an algorithm which creates a linked list of all the nodes at each depth.
#(e.g if you have a tree with depth D, you'll have D linked lists).

#Space: O(N)
#Time: O(N)
def linked_list_hash(head)
  level_hash = {}
  level_hash[1] = LinkedList.new(head)
  dfs(head, level_hash)
  level_hash
end

def dfs(node, level_hash)
  new_level = level_hash.keys.last+1
  level_hash[new_level] = LinkedList.new 
  adj(node).each do |child|
    level_hash[new_level].insert(child)
    dfs(child, level_hash)
  end
end

private 
def adj(node)
  [node.left, node.right]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue: `dfs` creates a new `level_hash[new_level]` each time it's called. But it gets called once for each node, so you'll end up overwriting your lists each time you find a new node. Not sure if there are other issues, but that one jumped out.

Your thought process seems to be OK. I would consider doing a BFS instead of a DFS for a problem like this, since you're trying to group things by depth. A DFS-based approach certainly works, though.

To check your code, you can start by reasoning through it and rubber-ducking it, which catches a lot of errors. Otherwise, there's simply no substitute for testing your code with actual input. I've been asked to do this a fair amount in interviews. When testing, you want to make sure to get good coverage of your code; try and go down all the different code paths. And try and find special cases to test (in this case, what if you pass in an empty tree? or one whose root has no children?)